# 2.8 Grease Pencil Depth Order

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil, draw-mode

I'd like to draw over geometry and use it as a reference for sculpting, but I'm having a problem with the depth ordering of the Grease pencil.

When it's set to Front, I see all of the line drawing, regardless of depth from the camera or objects in the way.

Setting it to 3d space results in the farthest lines from the camera subtracting from the closest lines.

Is there an option to get it look like the gif below in Depth Sorted? Where grease pencil lines are properly occluded by geometry? Or is that just something that's still a work in progress?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: One workaround I've found is converting the Grease Pencil layer into a curve, and playing with the transparency and color of that.
It gives me the functionality I need as far as the visual presentation, but it does mean I can't edit the linework without going through the whole drawing/conversion process over again.